# A reliable way to get the Dart VM service URL

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-vm

I'm building a no-code test automation tool for Flutter and Flutter driver.

For Flutter driver to connect it needs the url of the Dart VM Service.

In Flutter this is reported as follows when running a debug build.

```
A Dart VM Service on sdk gphone64 arm64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:56083/oOR_LvT4RT4=/
```

Over the past 3 years, the way this is reported has changed 4 times if I remember correctly.

I know because when it changes my software breaks .

This questions is to figure out if there's a way that I can query the device dart is running on to get the URL of an active Dart VM service.

I rely on regex now to get the URL out and it's more stable since I don't rely on things like "available at:" , but this is matching other urls that show up in the logs, that actually do match as well.

I would still like a more guaranteed URL retrieval implementation

Comment: Seems like a thing that the "--machine" flag to "flutter" should handle.

Answer (score 0):

### The Dart VM service URL is available via the `app.debugPort` event

You can get the Dart VM service URL for a running Flutter app reliably by listening to the `app.debugPort` event.

The `app.debugPort` event is sent by the `flutter daemon` server when a VM service port is available for a started app.

The `app.debugPort` event is also exposed via `flutter run --machine` so you can start the app with the command and handle the `app.debugPort` event.

More information:

- [Flutter Daemon](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/doc/daemon.md)
- [app.debugPort](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/doc/daemon.md#appdebugport)

### Sample Message:

Here is a sample message for the `app.debugPort` event. The Dart VM service URL is contained in the `wsUri` parameter.

```bash
[
  {
    "event": "app.debugPort",
    "params": {
      "appId": "fdcfd2e1-776d-4893-8fbf-c84f399f589d",
      "port": 51591,
      "wsUri": "ws://127.0.0.1:51591/TlaVIlUAMyg=/ws",
      "baseUri": "file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F04970CF-22B1-46A3-BCA9-BE7E654EDFCD/data/Containers/Data/Application/2A8AA29F-7C61-447B-9D60-98BCC712225D/tmp/demoJhXgVe/demo/"
    }
  }
]
```

### Sample Code:

From your tool, you can get the Dart VM service URL using the code below:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:process_run/process_run.dart';

...

const workingDirectory = 'path/to/flutter/project';

final shell = Shell(workingDirectory: workingDirectory);

// Run the Flutter app with the --machine argument
final process = await shell.run('flutter run --machine');

process[0].stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((message) {
  final Object? jsonData;

  try {
    jsonData = jsonDecode(message);
  } on FormatException {
    // The message is not valid JSON.
    return;
  }

  if (jsonData is List && jsonData.length == 1) {
    final payload = jsonData.single;

    if (payload is Map<String, Object?>) {
      final event = payload['event'];

      if (event == 'app.debugPort') {
        final params = payload['params'];

        if (params is Map<String, Object?>) {
          final vmServiceUri = params['wsUri'];

          print('Dart VM service URL is $vmServiceUri');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

*Note: The [Shell](https://pub.dev/documentation/process_run/latest/process_run.shell/Shell-class.html) object is available via the [process_run](https://pub.dev/packages/process_run) package.*

The console will print out this message:

```bash
Dart VM service URL is ws://127.0.0.1:51591/TlaVIlUAMyg=/ws
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate this response, it's very detailed, although it does not answer the question. I wanted to know if I can query the device to get the running VM service. The reason for that is because the app is installed via ADB, and is not run through Flutter, I don't have access to the code. The same for iOS, it's installed using the xcode tools. This means I need to get the vm service without the ability to start the app using Flutter.

Comment: @FilledStacks, you mentioned using regex to get the URL from the logs. How do you get the logs from installing the app using adb/xcode tools? I want to replicate that and use that to update the answer.

Comment: When you create a debug build and install it on an android device using adb you can use log cat to read all the logs. I then extract the dartVMService url from those logs.